# In Java, how do I most efficiently find an array within a JSON array based on the value of an element of the subarray?

Tags: java, arrays, json

So this is an example piece of JSON data that I'm working with.

```
{"season":"2016",
"week":"",
"positions":{
    "QB":[
        {
        "id":"2505245",
        "esbid":"PAL249055",
        "gsisPlayerId":"00-0021429",
        "firstName":"Carson",
        "lastName":"Palmer",
        "teamAbbr":"ARI",
        "opponentTeamAbbr":"",
        "position":"QB",
        "rank":"22",
        "statsLine":"",
        "stats":
        {
            "PassYds":false,
            "PassTDs":false,
            "Int":false,
            "RushYds":false,
            "RushTDs":false,
            "RecYds":false,
            "RecTds":false,
            "FumTD":false,
            "TwoPt":false,
            "FumLost":false
        },
        "pts":"85.00",
        "projectedPts":"277.46",
        "status":""
        },
        {
        "id":"2495748",
        "esbid":"STA482517",
        "gsisPlayerId":"00-0025430",
        "firstName":"Drew",
        "lastName":"Stanton",
        "teamAbbr":"ARI",
        "opponentTeamAbbr":"",
        "position":"QB",
        "rank":"42",
        "statsLine":"",
        "stats":
        {
            "PassYds":false,
            "PassTDs":false,
            "Int":false,
            "RushYds":false,
            "RushTDs":false,
            "RecYds":false,
            "RecTds":false,
            "FumTD":false,
            "TwoPt":false,
            "FumLost":false
        },
        "pts":"11.06",
        "projectedPts":"7.36",
        "status":""}]
    }
}
```

Now I have a huge list with hundreds of different players set up like this and I would like to be able to get the data for a single player. In this case, let's say I want to find the stats for Carson Palmer. That would mean I want to look in the QB JSON array to find a sub array which includes `firstName:Carson` and `lastName:Palmer`.

How would I do this with a library like GSON?

Comment: Gson isn't meant for queries.  Try this https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath

Comment: Update the question to clarify 'efficiently'. This requires full traversal, as specified - and 'efficiently' probably means 'easily' or 'with minimal effort' or similar. In fact, the qualifier can be omitted entirely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[JsonPath](https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath)

From all positions, find all elements with first name Carson, last name Palmer

```
$.positions[*][?(@.firstName == "Carson" && @.lastName == "Palmer")]
```

Add `.stats` to the end of that or parse it out yourself from that object

Note: that returns an array. Multiple players could have that name.

---

Alternatively, you are getting this data from some server, and you should perform the player search server-side